# browserify and babel namespace error React

Tags: reactjs, namespaces, browserify, babeljs

New to browserify: I have a normal js file with some react components grouped in a namespace like:

```
var myNameSpace= {
'reactFunc1': React....,
'reactFunc2': React....,
'reactFunc3': React....,
'nonreactFunc1' function(..)
}
```

And in some other js file I'm trying to use:

```
myNameSpace.reactFunc1(...);
```

this works fine when I tranform jsx to js using babel.

But when I browerify the files using the command  `browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] some.js someOther.js`

`myNameSpace not defined`

What I'm doing wrong here. Is there any way to get this working without much hastle / code change?

Comment: Are you using the namespace on a different module? How are you importing the namespace?

Comment: @Tzach I'm not importing it. And there is no module here.. I have 2 seperate js files... when I don't browserify the files... `myNameSpace.reactFunc1` is defined but when I browserify `myNameSpace.reactFunc2` is undefined

Comment: I'm not sure how to make this `var myNameSpace= {
'reactFunc1': React....,
'reactFunc2': React....,
'reactFunc3': React....,
'nonreactFunc1' function(..)
}` as module and export it with name `myNameSpace` and use this in other js file and do something like `myNameSpace.reactFunc1(...);`

Comment: Got you. That's because when using browserify each file is a module, and the `var` definitions are local to that module. You'll need to import one module into the other, or do `window.myNameSpace = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here, using modules or using the global namespace.

When using modules, you will need to export the namespace from the first module and `require` it in the other module:

```
module.exports = {
    'reactFunc1': React....,
}
```

Then in the other file

```
var myNameSpace = require('first_module');
```

The other option (less preferred) is to use the global `window` object:

```
window.myNameSpace = {
    'reactFunc1': React....,
}
```

Then in the other file:

```
window.myNameSpace.reactFunc1()
```

Comment: @NishanthMatha Give your modules meaningful names, that way it's easier to keep in mind what does what.